# OnBackPressed in a fragment to return to a previous Tab

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity which consists of two Fragments(Fragment1 and Fragment2).In turn Fragment2 has three fragment tabs(Tab1,Tab2,Tab3).How to implement onBackPressed so that if i am in Tab 3 and press back button it should go to Tab2 and then to Tab1 on another click of back button.
I have implemented onBackPressed() in my Activity. As i am new to android i dont know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) for more details

Comment: I have tried this.But its not working.Directly it will close the application on backbutton click.

Comment: No its not showing any error.Should i add addToBackStack in my code??

Comment: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/actionbarsherlock-side-menu-navigation-nested-viewpager-fragment-tabs-tutorial/        This is the link of tutorial i have followed to implement all these.It has nested fragments.